# Google EndPoint Authentication with Firebase from Google App Engine - No auth token is contained in the HTTP request

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-security

I am using this :

- Front End with Google App Engine(GAE) the javascript section

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.8/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "XXXXX",
      authDomain: "id-aplication.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://id-aplication.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "id-aplication.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "00000"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>

          function init(){
        
         var apiRoot = "//id-aplication.appspot.com/_ah/api";
         gapi.client.load('Api', "v1", callback, apiRoot);
         
        }
        
        function createUserFirebase(){ 
         var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
         var request = gapi.client.Api.createUserFirebase(user);
         request.execute(callBackResponse);
        }
        
        
        function callback(){
         
        
         btn = document.getElementById("input_create_user_firebase");
         btn.onclick=function(){createUserFirebase();};
         btn.value="Click me for Create User Firebase";
        
         
        }
```

- BackEnd with Google Cloud EndPoint

```js
@Api(name = "Api", 
 version = "v1",
 namespace = 
  @ApiNamespace( 
   ownerDomain = "api.example.com",
   ownerName = "api.example.com", packagePath = "" ),
 issuers = {
      @ApiIssuer(
        name = "firebase",
        issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/id-aplication",
        jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
    },
    issuerAudiences = {
        @ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "id-aplication")}
    )
 public class SharedRoadApi {
    @ApiMethod(
     name = "firebase_user",
     httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET,
     authenticators = {EspAuthenticator.class},
     issuerAudiences = {@ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = {"id-aplication"})}
     )
    public Email firebase_user(User user) throws UnauthorizedException {
   if (user == null) {
     throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
   }

   Email response = new Email();
   response.setEmail(user.getEmail());
   return response;
    }
   }
```

- Authentication with Firebase

The steps are:

- Login with Firebase authentication
- Call the java method in the Google Cloud EndPoint, and this dont give the messae "Invalid credentials", this mean that authenticate
- But even if you login the method give error,

> com.google.api.server.spi.auth.EspAuthenticator authenticate:
>   Authentication failed: com.google.api.auth.UnauthenticatedException:
>   No auth token is contained in the HTTP request
>   (EspAuthenticator.java:86)

I would appreciate it if anyone can tell me what I should do specifically or add, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

any reference to gapi.client.Api.createUserFirebase(user)? I couldn't find any document or code implementation of this method.

BTW, since I don't have enough reputations to add a comment, we will use this thread to collect more details to help troubleshoot this issue. We will replace this with a real answer soon.

Comment: Hello Wencheng, gapi.client is how you call any application of Google EndPoint, and @Api(name = "Api") is in this case the name of my application is "Api" that is the reason that you use gapi.client.Api and createUserFirebase is finally the java Method that i create

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems that the Javascript client is not attaching an auth token with the request. To authenticate a request, Endpoints requires a JWT to be attached with HTTP auth header in the format of "Authorization: bearer ${JWT}". If you're running the Javascript client in a browser, can you open the dev console to see what headers are set in the outgoing HTTP request? In Chrome, this can be found under the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate the client: the endpoints server is expecting authentication from the client, but receives none. More fine-grained information is to be found in the [Using Endpoints in a JavaScript Client](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/consume_js) document, specifically in the subsection “Adding authentication support with OAuth 2.0”.